# How do I make aggregate in mongoldb witch returns the subject and the number of subjects

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation

I have a database in mongodb that have three fields one the pageID, comment and the other the date.

I need to aggregate all pageID that are the same and return the count of numbers of pageID in descending order by date. I need to do this in java. Get the count of pageId that are the same.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c93b148e3c73c03bb9b528b"), "idPagina" : "23", "date" : ISODate("2019-03-21T15:44:08.434Z"), "email" : "edw@jreww.com", "body" : "adnalf" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c93bf4ae3c73c0598e94b44"), "idPagina" : "45", "date" : ISODate("2019-03-21T16:43:53.695Z"), "email" : "ewfn@fewr.com", "body" : "jklewnf" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c93fb6fe3c73c054600c983"), "idPagina" : "78", "date" : ISODate("2019-03-21T21:00:30.882Z"), "email" : "raphael@me.com", "body" : "jhsdbclkdbclkd" }
```

Trying to aggregate but i need to convert to java:

```
db.posts.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$idPagina", num_posts : {$sum : 1}}}])
{ "_id" : "60", "num_posts" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "56", "num_posts" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "23", "num_posts" : 31 }
{ "_id" : "30", "num_posts" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "78", "num_posts" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "45", "num_posts" : 5 }

MongoCollection<Document> coll = MongoFactory.getCollection(db_name, db_collection);

List<Bson> aggregation = Arrays.asList(

        Aggregates.group("$idPagina", Accumulators.sum("count", 1)),

        Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending("date")),

        Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(Projections.excludeId(), Projections.computed("idPagina", "$_id"), Projections.include("count"))));


Iterator<Document> sortedList = coll.aggregate(aggregation).iterator();

List<PostCount> result = new ArrayList<PostCount>();
```

Now how can make a pagination? Get 20 pages than get the other 20 pages after the last one?
ex:

```
docs  = coll.find().limit(postPerPage).sort(new BasicDBObject("date", -1));
```

**The date sorting is not working.**

Comment: Can you post a example of your schema ?

Comment: Check this: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-grouping-example/